# Push images into Gstreamer pipeline

Tags: c, opencv, gstreamer

I have been following many examples about pushing an image into a Gstreamer pipeline but still I can't make my code work.

Any suggestion (beside telling me to try with Gstreamer1.0 instead of 0.10) will be very appreciated. I want to understand what is wrong in the following script that feeds an `appsrc` element with a jpeg image. Later I will use the same code to feed openCv images that I obtain from my camera but first I want to understand the basics by making this simple example work.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define VIDEO_CAPS "video/x-raw-rgb,bpp=8,depth=8,width=640,height=360,framerate=5/1,red_mask=224,green_mask=28,blue_mask=3,endianness=1234;"


/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it to callbacks */
guint64 imagecounter=1;

typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *pipeline, *app_source;
  GstElement *video_convert, *video_sink;
  GstElement *image_manage;
  guint64 num_samples;   /* Number of samples generated so far (for timestamp generation) */

  guint sourceid;        /* To control the GSource */

  GMainLoop *main_loop;  /* GLib's Main Loop */
} CustomData;

/* This method is called by the idle GSource in the mainloop, to feed CHUNK_SIZE bytes into appsrc.
 * The idle handler is added to the mainloop when appsrc requests us to start sending data (need-data signal)
 * and is removed when appsrc has enough data (enough-data signal).
 */
static gboolean push_data (CustomData *data) {
  GstBuffer *buffer;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  int i;
  gint8 *raw;
  gint num_samples; 
  gfloat freq;
  int size,depth,height,width,step,channels;
  guchar *data1;
  IplImage* img;
  g_print("push_data is beginning\n");


  img=cvLoadImage("frame1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 

  height    = img->height;  
  width     = img->width;
  step      = img->widthStep;
  channels  = img->nChannels;
  depth     = img->depth;
  data1      = (guchar *)img->imageData;
  num_samples = height*width*channels;

  g_print("height %d\n",height);
  g_print("width %d\n",width);
  g_print("widthStep %d\n",step); 
  g_print("nChannels %d\n",channels);
  g_print("depth %d\n",depth);
  g_print("image_number %" G_GUINT64_FORMAT "\n", imagecounter);
  g_print("sizeof guchar: %lu\n",sizeof(guchar));

  /* Create a new empty buffer */
  buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc (num_samples); // guint size :the size in bytes of the new buffer's data.
  size = GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buffer);
  g_print("nSize %d\n",size);
  g_print("buffer initialized\n");

  /* Set its timestamp and duration */
  GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (imagecounter, GST_SECOND, 5 );
  imagecounter += 1;
  GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (num_samples, GST_SECOND,5);

  memcpy( (guchar *)GST_BUFFER_DATA( buffer ), data1, GST_BUFFER_SIZE( buffer ) );
  g_print("image data copied into buffer\n");
  data->num_samples += num_samples;

  /* Push the buffer into the appsrc */
  g_signal_emit_by_name (data->app_source, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
  g_print("buffer pushed\n");
  /* Free the buffer now that we are done with it */
  gst_buffer_unref (buffer);
  g_print("buffer unreferenced\n");
  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
     g_printerr("something wrong in sending data");
    /* We got some error, stop sending data */
    return FALSE;
  }
  g_print("push_data is ending\n");
  return TRUE;
}

/* This signal callback triggers when appsrc needs data. Here, we add an idle handler
 * to the mainloop to start pushing data into the appsrc */
static void start_feed (GstElement *source, guint size, CustomData *data) {
  if (data->sourceid == 0) {
    g_print ("Start feeding\n");
    data->sourceid = g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) push_data, data);
    g_print ("push_data started\n");
  }
}

/* This callback triggers when appsrc has enough data and we can stop sending.
 * We remove the idle handler from the mainloop */
static void stop_feed (GstElement *source, CustomData *data) {
  if (data->sourceid != 0) {
    g_print ("Stop feeding\n");
    g_source_remove (data->sourceid);
    data->sourceid = 0;
  }
}


/* This function is called when an error message is posted on the bus */
static void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  GError *err;
  gchar *debug_info;

  /* Print error details on the screen */
  gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
  g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
  g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
  g_clear_error (&err);
  g_free (debug_info);

  g_main_loop_quit (data->main_loop);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CustomData data;
  gchar *video_caps_text;
  GstCaps *video_caps;
  GstBus *bus;

  /* Initialize cumstom data structure */
  memset (&data, 0, sizeof (data));

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  data.app_source = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "video_source");
  data.video_convert = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace", "csp");
  data.video_sink = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2sink", "video_sink");
  data.image_manage= gst_element_factory_make("imagefreeze","image_manage");
  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!data.pipeline || !data.app_source || !data.video_convert || !data.video_sink || !data.image_manage) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Configure appsrc */
  video_caps_text = g_strdup_printf (VIDEO_CAPS);
  video_caps = gst_caps_from_string (video_caps_text);
  if( !GST_IS_CAPS(video_caps) ) {
                g_printerr("Error creating Caps for OpenCV-Source, exiting...");
                exit( 1 );
            }
  g_object_set (data.app_source, "caps", video_caps, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (data.app_source, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (start_feed), &data);
  g_signal_connect (data.app_source, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK (stop_feed), &data);

  /* Configure v4l2loopback videosink*/
  //g_object_set (data.video_sink, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);

  /* Link all elements that can be automatically linked because they have "Always" pads */
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.app_source, data.image_manage, data.video_convert, data.video_sink, NULL);

if ( gst_element_link_many ( data.app_source, data.video_convert,data.video_sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;}
/* 

  /* Instruct the bus to emit signals for each received message, and connect to the interesting signals */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* Start playing the pipeline */
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Create a GLib Main Loop and set it to run */
  data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  g_main_loop_run (data.main_loop);

  /* Free resources */
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

After a couple of buffers have been sent I receive the following output:

> `Error received from element video_source: Internal data flow error`.

```
Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstAppSrc:video_source:
            streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

Comment: did you try changing the `appsrc` caps to `image/jpeg, height=360, width=640, framerate=5/1` then parsing and decoding the jpeg with `jpegparse` and `jpegdec` and linking that against `ffmpegcolorspace`. Also, if you want to DISPLAY just use `autovideosink` instead of `v4l2sink`.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! After adding the jpegparse and jpegdec elements I don't receive that error anymore and the buffers are pushed without problem. But even if I use autovideosink I still cannot visualize that image! When I run the program no windows show up! Any further suggestion? By the way, I am using v4l2sink because it is necessary for my final purpose but I can work on it later.

Comment: I tried to add a control on the value returned by the calling gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING); the value is different from the expected GST_STATE_CHANGE_SUCCESS. So I guess my problem is that the pipeline can not be set to play state. But I don't know why. I am sorry if all these questions are stupid but I am not familiar at all with Gstreamer..

Comment: The next step is to turn on gstreamer debugging. put `GST_DEBUG=*:5` in font of your executable when you run it to get debug output from all of your elements to help you narrow it down.

Comment: beside the suggestion to try to use the debugger, does anyone have any link to some useful example from which I can learn? I can also switch to Gstreamer1.0 since I found that a Gstreamer developer passed all the tutorials code from 0.10 to 1.0. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work. I switched to Gstreamer1.0 and everything has been much easier. I still don't know what was the problem in the old code but since this new one is ok, no need to waste other time on it.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

static GMainLoop *loop;

static void
cb_need_data (GstElement *appsrc,
          guint       unused_size,
          gpointer    user_data)
{
  static gboolean white = FALSE;
  static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;
  GstBuffer *buffer;
  guint size,depth,height,width,step,channels;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  IplImage* img;
  guchar *data1;
  GstMapInfo map;

  img=cvLoadImage("frame1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
  height    = img->height;  
  width     = img->width;
  step      = img->widthStep;
  channels  = img->nChannels;
  depth     = img->depth;
  data1      = (guchar *)img->imageData;
  size = height*width*channels;

  buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);
  gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
  memcpy( (guchar *)map.data, data1,  gst_buffer_get_size( buffer ) );
  /* this makes the image black/white */
  //gst_buffer_memset (buffer, 0, white ? 0xff : 0x0, size);

  white = !white;

  GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = timestamp;
  GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 2);

  timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer);

  g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    /* something wrong, stop pushing */
    g_main_loop_quit (loop);
  }
}

gint
main (gint   argc,
      gchar *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *conv, *videosink;

  /* init GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* setup pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");
  appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "source");
  conv = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "conv");
  videosink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "videosink");

  /* setup */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",
        gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
                     "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
                     "width", G_TYPE_INT, 640,
                     "height", G_TYPE_INT, 360,
                     "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1, 1,
                     NULL), NULL);
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
  gst_element_link_many (appsrc, conv, videosink, NULL);
  //g_object_set (videosink, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);
  /* setup appsrc */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc),
        "stream-type", 0,
        "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (cb_need_data), NULL);

  /* play */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  /* clean up */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
  g_main_loop_unref (loop);

  return 0;
  }
```